# wget: error getting response: Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: wget

Attempt to retrieve [entware script from a RT-N16 router outfitted with DD-WRT](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Installing_Entware) returns a wget error:

```
root@DD-WRT:/opt# wget http://bin.entware.net/mipselsf-k3.4/installer/generic.sh
Connecting to bin.entware.net (104.27.176.50:80)
wget: error getting response: Address family not supported by protocol
```

An Ubuntu box is connected to the router and can wget generic.sh.  The test router resides on a LAN and is not directly connected to the modem (internet).  I believe this does not make a difference because the Ubuntu box can wget the target.

The wget error must be corrected because generic.sh relies on wget.

From the router's CLI: What diagnostics can be performed identify the issue and corrective action?

Comment: It seems to me that you're not running Wget, but a busybox version of Wget which is the same name but an entirely different application.

Comment: Is there a CLI test that confirm wget is a busybox version?

Comment: `wget --version` should ideally tell you the difference

Answer (score 1):

Got the same response on ESXi 7 cli and **"--no-check-certificate"** worked for me so  `wget --no-check-certificate http://bin.entware.net/mipselsf-k3.4/installer/generic.sh` should also work for you.

Comment: This did not resolve the issue for me.

Comment: Solution that ended up working for me: enable http client with `esxcli network firewall ruleset set -e true -r httpClient` and then verify it is enabled with `esxcli network firewall ruleset list | grep -E '^Name|^---|http'` curl should then work as intended.